# Nodejs real time pull Stream Instagram photo via hashtag

Tags: javascript, node.js, instagram-api

Is there a way / node lib package that can do real time pull instagram photo via hashtag?

Comment: Is there a way you could at least try it first ? If you have, is there a way you could share whats not working ?

Comment: I've tried instagram-node but have no idea how to make it work for subscription. Is subscription suppose to pull through real time? [instagram-node](https://github.com/totemstech/instagram-node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

where {tag-name} is the tag you are searching and ACCESS-TOKEN is the access token of the registered user who has granted you the permission.